# Showing a recursive sequence is Cauchy 5

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

$(b_n)$ is a sequence such that $b_1 = 1$ and $b_{n+1} = − \dfrac{1}{5}(b_n−2)$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $(b_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I can see that the sequence converges to $\dfrac{1}{3}$ but I am struggling to prove this using the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

observe that

$$b_{n+1}-\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{1}{5}\left(b_n-\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

$$=\frac{2}{3}\frac{(-1)^n}{5^n}$$

Comment: That helps to prove convergence, which implies Cauchy-ness here, but the question asks to prove Cauchy-ness "using the definition of a Cauchy sequence."